# Profiling Excel addins with dotTrace

Tags: .net, excel, dottrace

I am trying to profile Excel addins written in C# with dotTrace.

I am able to connect to excel and profile my code when I select "attach to process" in dottrace, but when I want to use the "standalone application" mode (that allows for more options), then dottrace seems to think that excel is loading .Net v.2 and so it doesn't see my addins.

Any idea about how to force dottrace to profile .net 4.0 addins?

EDIT: I found that some other addins was loading .NET v2 before my addins were loading v4, and that dottrace takes the first one. Any way I can force which one to trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch between two processes with same names and ID's, but with 2 different CLR versions in the controller window (above controller buttons).